# Google intensity map is not getting filled up

Tags: json, google-visualization

I have a google intensity map which is appearing on the web page however it is not getting filled up according to the different states. Here is the code for it -

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geomap']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap() {
        console.log("In draw map function");
      var test = {{states|safe}};
      console.log(test);  console.log(test);
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{states|safe}});

      var options = {};
      options['region'] = 'US'
      options['dataMode'] = 'regions';

      var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
      var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
      geomap.draw(data, options);
  };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='map_canvas'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

The data that I am passing over looks like this -

```
[["State","No of users"],["AL",1957392],["AK",324183],["AZ",1837630],["AR",1062588],....]
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? I am just getting the default map of US. It is not getting filled up according to the intensity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `resolution` option to `'provinces'` to get a map of the states:

```
options['resolution'] = 'provinces';
```

Also, the GeoMaps are deprecated, use the new GeoCharts instead.  Load the `'geochart'` package:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
```

and use a `GeoChart` object:

```
var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);
geochart.draw(data, options);
```